# Can't turn informational/warning messages off

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Every time I'm going through an entire file searching of occurrences of a string, VS shows a poop-up notifying me about that. I've unchecked the option to continue that behavior at number of times - to no avail.

[image]

I went to options and unchecked it there as well (see image for verification) but every time I restart VS, the settings in back there - checked and unaffected. I'm out of ideas what to try to remedy it. (Googled it. I haven't found anything that I recognized as useful.)

Comment: Maybe you can de-tune the sarcasm a bit when you realize that this is of course not normal.  More likely that somebody will take you serious and tell you what might be wrong with your machine.

Comment: Tried running visual studio as admin and then disable the setting?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I can definitely de-tune the sarcasm. I didn't realize I was over the limit when I typed. Now, after your remark, I'm prone to agree. I stand corrected. So is the text, too.

Comment: @MarkJansen I hadn't. Now I have - good suggestion. Sadly, the setting's still misbehaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those settings are saved (when you close Visual Studio) in this registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Find

```
"ShowEndOfSearch"="1"
"ShowNoFound"="1"
"ShowAllReplacementsNotAllowed"="1"
"ShowSomeReplacementsNotAllowed"="1"
"ShowNoMore"="1"
"ShowFindStart"="1"
"ShowCancel"="1"
"ShowCancelBeforeReplacementsMade"="1"
"ShowReplaceInFilesWarning"="1"
```

Do you have access to that key? Try setting these values to "0" in regedit.

Comment: Yupp, that solved my problem (kind of, at least - I still prefer not to have to go RegEdit to set stuff in VS, hehe). As I wrote before, Code Lens seems to be missing from my options and I haven't found it as a key in the registry (following your answer). Suggestions on that? Suggestions on how to make VS behave to begin with?

Comment: You need to find out WHY your Studio fails to write to those keys. How was it installed? By your Admin? For everyone? I (being a programmer) blame faulty installation :) Also, you can run a Process Monitor from Sysinternals (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb896645.aspx) to see all registry access and its result.

Comment: Well, I'll try to reinstall the whole shabang, as it worked before and "*magically*" stopped. I probably installed something extra without realizing that it'd affect the VS installation. +1 for a bunch of great hints.